# Linux networking and routing

Tags: linux, routing, ipsec, iproute2

I have 3 networks:

```
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.11.0/24
192.168.50.0/24
```

`192.168.1.0/24` and `192.168.11.0/24` are connected to each other through an IPSec tunnel, and `192.168.11.0/24` and `192.168.50.0/24` are connected to each other in the same way.

```
[ 192.168.1.0/24 ] <--------> [ 192.168.11.0/24 ] <--------> [ 192.168.50.0/24 ]
```

I am on my local machine on the `1.0/24` subnet, and I am trying to set-up routing for the `50.0/24` subnet, using the router at `11.0/24` as the next-hop address. Routing is set-up as follows:

```
ip route add 192.168.11.0/24 via 192.168.1.1
    (this route is unnecessary as the router handles this implicitly)
ip route add 192.168.50.0/25 via 192.168.11.254
    (At this point, I get: RTNETLINK answers: No such process)
```

Am I doing some command incorrectly, or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the way this routing works?

Answer (score 2):

The gateway address MUST be on the local network.  That is, your system must be able to directly communicate with any gateway you specify.

What you probably want/need is this.

```
ip route add 192.168.50.0/25 via 192.168.1.1
```